# How to resolve Node error "Httpd Failed"?

Tags: webserver, apache

I made some changes to our sites httpd.conf file and possibly some other things in the past when I was tinkering with node.js and trying to set it up on our server.

Our server crashes every now and then and I haven't been able to figure out the problem, but I only just realised that it's probably being caused by something that I did while tinkering with node.js.

Here is a screenshot of our problem:

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening? I have tried resetting the httpd.conf file in the Apache directory using the /scripts/rebuildhttpdconf fix but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: try running `grep /dev/null /etc/apache2 -r` to search for a line like `DocumentRoot /dev/null` which should be a problem in most cases...

Comment: Yep. Found many more than 1 line of apache/logs/error_log:Warning: DocumentRoot [/dev/null] does not exist. Thanks! What should I do now?

Comment: Are there any search results other than in the logs (we already know that this might be an issue).

Which distribution are you using (as they use different configuration paths)

Comment: Yep, there is this one: "apache/etc/httpd.conf:    DocumentRoot /dev/null" and a huge weird one in 'apache/build/libtool'

Comment: try changing that line in httpd.conf (to e.g. `DocumentRoot /var/www`)

Then restart apache.

Comment: Okay. Is there any quick way I can find the line with vi?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19247/discussion-between-mreithub-and-sneaksta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a chat with @Sneaksta and digging around in the error_log we found following error message:

```
[Thu Nov 08 12:22:24 2012] [emerg] (43)Identifier removed: couldn't grab the accept mutex
```

According to a blog post over at [michaelwlucas.com](http://blather.michaelwlucas.com/archives/678) this looks like an issue with apache's internal mutex. Putting the following line to your apache configuration should work around this issue (by simply using in-memory mutexes instead of lock files):

```
AcceptMutex posixsem
```